# [type=checkbox]:checked content: "x";

Tags: css, wordpress, css-selectors

I'm having a css selector issue here: http://hrrrthrrr.com.s153901.gridserver.com/heyheyok/contact/

Basically the "select all that apply" section should put a "x" in the small gray boxes to the left of the inputs when checked.

```
.form-check-fields {
    .wpcf7-list-item {
        [type=checkbox]:checked + .wpcf7-list-item-label {
                content: "x";
                text-align: center;
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks for reading!

Comment: The selector in your actual stylesheet ends with `+ .wpcf7-list-item-label:before` and not just `+ .wpcf7-list-item-label`. The problem must be somewhere else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Test insert this code

```
   [type="checkbox"]:checked + .wpcf7-list-item-label:before {
       border: 1px solid;
      color: #FF0000;
       content: "x";
       position: absolute;
       text-align: center;
      z-index: 1000;
   }
```

[image]

do you mean this.....

Comment: This is not the first time someone has had to fix the formatting on your posts for you. Please review your [revisions](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2477221?tab=responses&sort=revisions) to learn how to format your posts correctly.